# Excel VBA Read txt files to string variable - Multiple Languages

Tags: vba, character-encoding

I try to read mutiple txt files with Excel VBA and store their file name and content in an array. However I have a hard time with character sets, since the txt file can contain a variety of languages. Is there a charset that supports all languages or how can I solve the below described problem?

Here is the code I have

```
Function create_Txt_Content_Array(file_count As Integer, path As String, Optional strType As String) As String()

Dim createArray() As String
Dim file As Variant
Dim read_file As Integer
Dim absolut_path As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim text_content As String
Dim objStream

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "utf-8"

ReDim createArray(file_count - 1, 1)

    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    file = Dir(path & strType)
    absolut_path = path & file
    j = 0
    While (file <> "")
        objStream.Open
        objStream.LoadFromFile (absolut_path)
        text_content = objStream.ReadText()
        objStream.Close
        createArray(j, 0) = file
        createArray(j, 1) = text_content
        Debug.Print (text_content)
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
        file = Dir
        absolut_path = path & file
    Wend
    
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

- The first file contains Portuguese: no problem
- The second file contains English: no problem
- The third file contains Hindi: not working

There are other languages like Korean, Japanese and others following.

[image: This is what the array looks like]

Comment: What do you intend to do with the loaded array? `Debug.Print (text_content)` and text shown in Locals window may not be eloquent. Try using a testing sheet and use `Worksheets("Tests").Range("A1").value = text_content`. How the returned text does look?

Comment: Be aware that the VBA-environment cannot handle those character sets, therefore displaying ????. That doesn't necessarily mean that the data you read is not correctly imported. Dump the data into Excel and check what is displayed.

Comment: debug.print there is just for debug. eventually content will end up in excel cells

Comment: @FaneDuru you were right! Writing it directly to a sheet cell works!

Comment: This means that `UTF-8` works in all cases. I also asked **What do you intend to do with the loaded array**... An array is volatile, you cannot keep it for using it next time when open your computer. So, you need to do something with the respective data. Do you send it in a different application? Do you want writing it in specific Excel sheets? Or what? I am asking not from curiosity. We may try helping on that, or about the way you declared the array. If intending to place the content in a sheet range, the declaration is a little strange. It is a 2D array, but zero based (with two columns)...

Comment: @FaneDuru the intention was to also manipulate strings by substringing parts and cross checking (source vs target language) file names. However this can be accomplished elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing it directly to a sheet cell does the trick